# Passed event handler not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have the following class (only left the necessary details for clarity):

```
class CalendarAndUsage extends React.
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleClickOnDay = this.handleClickOnDay.bind(this);

    }

    handleClickOnDay() {
        console.log("wtf");
    }

    render() (
             return (<Calendar onDayClick={this.handleClickOnDay} />
        )
    }
}
```

The Calendar class looks as follow:

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
    render() {

        let weeks = this.props.weeks.map((week) => {
                return (
                    <Week onDayClick={this.props.onDayClick} />
                )
            }
        );

        return (
            <div className="calendar">
                {weeks}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And finally the Week class code:

```
class Week extends React.Component {
    render() {
       /* lots of uninteresting code */
       return <OffMonthDay onClick={() => this.props.onDayClick()}>{`${dayOfTheWeek} ${date.day}`}</OffMonthDay>
    }
```

But for God knows what reason, whenever the OffMonthDay element is clicked, the onClick event isn't firing. Am I doing something completely wrong?

EDIT:

OffMonthDay is pretty simple:

```
function OffMonthDay(props) {
    return (
        <div className="col-md-1 off-month-day day">
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: what does `OffMonthDay` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because `OffMonthDay` doesn't have an `onClick` event.

It should look like this

```
function OffMonthDay(props) {
    return (
        <div 
           onClick={props.onClick}
           className="col-md-1 off-month-day day"
        >
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Darnit, I thought you could circumvent that by using "onClick" on the element when passing props... guess it doesn't work like that! Is there a better way to pass event handlers when  you need to go more than 2 layers deep (as illustrated here)?

Comment: You can only attach an event handler to a valid DOM element. Not so sure if there is a better way, but [redux actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) could probably help you with that :)